# When working with images in MATLAB, what do myImage(:,:,1), myImage(:,:,2), myImage(:,:,3) etc mean?

Tags: matlab

Please help me to understand the 3 lines of this code:

```
function [F]=get_image_features(Icolored) 
% Icolored is the image coming from the line 
% F=get_image_features(I); from create_learning_set.m file
%% get R G B components of the sub-image

R = Icolored(:,:,1);
G = Icolored(:,:,2);
B = Icolored(:,:,3);

%% Get random 128 x 128 sub-image
% R=rnad_subimage(R);
% G=rnad_subimage(G);
% B=rnad_subimage(B);

%% get the features of each channel
Rf=get_channel_features(R);
Gf=get_channel_features(G);
Bf=get_channel_features(B);

%% the feature vector
F=[Rf Gf Bf];

end
```

These 3 lines are:

```
R = Icolored(:,:,1);
G = Icolored(:,:,2);
B = Icolored(:,:,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

An image called `Icolored` is read by **matlab** as a three-dimensional matrix with one layer for each colour component.

For example, given a 20 x 20 image:

```
%% Icolored is 20 x 20 x 3
R = Icolored(:,:,1);
G = Icolored(:,:,2);
B = Icolored(:,:,3);
```

`R`, `G`, `B` are the respective layers, each is a 20 x 20 matrix of colour intensity values.

Comment: It is usually called a "color channel", not a "layer".

Comment: This of course does not change the fact that it can be visualised as a "layer" in a three-dimensional matrix, for those so spatially inclined.